# Depth of BFS Tree With Different Root Nodes

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, proof-writing, trees

I need to either prove or disprove that for any node of a graph, the depth of the BFS tree using this node as root is always the same.  My intuition is that this is true, but I'm having difficulty constructing a proof, is this correct?  If so, could someone offer a hint?  If not, could someone suggest a counterexample?

Comment: **Hint**: the depth of any node in the breadth-first tree is exactly its distance to the root node.

Comment: I can extend this to say that the depth of any node in a breadth-first tree is exactly the shortest distance to the root node, correct?

Comment: x @user: Um, yes, that's what I said. ("Distance" without qualification usually means "shortest distance").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always true. You just need to show that the vertices on the $i$'th level of BFS tree, are the vertices with distance $i$ to the root. So the depth of BFS tree will be always the longest shortest distance from the root to other vertices in the graph.